# Минус — это тире или дефис?

Tags: знак-минус

Каким знаком мы показываем, когда пишем, минус: дефисом, малым тире или большим тире?

> -3/–3 /—3 + 4 = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При написании обычных текстов используются четыре *горизонтальные* черточки:
дефис **-**
минус **−** (перенесен из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0))
короткое тире **–** (Alt 0150)
обычное тире **—** (Alt 0151)

> Минус и дефис не являются, вопреки распространенному мнению, одним и тем же знаком.
> Знак минуса в хороших шрифтах выровнен по высоте прописных знаков (каковыми являются цифры) и употребляется в математических формулах.

Не знаю, как у других, но с помощью моей клавиатуры точно изобразить знак "минус" невозможно. Вместо него обычно я использую короткое тире.

Давайте посмотрим, есть ли разница:

36 – 2 = 34, **36 – 2 = 34** (скопировано [отсюда](https://o-krohe.ru/math/slogenie-vychitanie/do-50/));
36 − 5 = 31, **36 − 5 = 31** (из Википедии);
36 - 5 = 31, **36 - 5 = 31** (на клавиатуре использован якобы знак "минус");
36 – 5 = 31, **36 – 5 = 31** (на клавиатуре использовано короткое тире).

Если не выделять "жирным", то разница чувствуется только в примере с дефисом.
Это означает, что мы его [дефис] вместо минуса все-таки использовать не будем. Лучше применять короткое тире (что в большинстве случаев пользователи и делают).

Ну... или копировать минус из "Википедии" (можно закладочку сделать).
Правильно: −3 + 4 = 1.

Дополнительная информация
[Тире, минус и дефис, или Черты русской типографики](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/97/)
[Тире, короткое тире, минус, дефис](https://webstyle.sfu-kras.ru/tire-defis)
[Различие тире и дефиса](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0/)

Comment: Римулик, я не к месту, но там, где мы разговаривали, Вам уже не поступят мои комменты; а где ж ещё-то поговорить? О_о Вот эти вопрос и ответ - они ж об абстрактном, об идеале, страшно далеки оне от народа (полиграфии). Я не заглядываю, потому что никому не нужны мои опытопознания или литературный слух, - просят правил, а я их никогда не изучала и гуглить толком не умею. Кидайте вопросы по редактированию!

Comment: А в математических примерах знаки нужно отбивать пробелами?

Comment: Максим, я оформила дополнительный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Дополнительный ответ

*А в математических примерах знаки нужно отбивать пробелами?*

[**Ответы**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) справочной службы русского языка

**Вопрос № 284233**
Пробелы нужны. Знаки математических действий и соотношений (**+** , **–** , **х** , **:** , **/** , **=**) отбивают от смежных символов и чисел.

**Вопрос № 277443**
**1)** Нужны ли пробелы между цифрами и знаками в математических уравнениях?
2+2=4 или 2 + 2 = 4

"Знаки математических действий и соотношений отбивают от смежных символов и чисел на 2 пункта, а знаки положительности или отрицательности значения величины набирают слитно с последующим числом". См.: А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова, Справочник издателя и автора. М., 2003. П. 6.4.4.

• А вот знаки ***плюс**, **минус*** и ***плюс-минус*** со следующим за ним числом пишутся без пробела.

Правильно:
2 + 2 = 4
2023 – 24 = 1999
–62; –0,62; ±0,25; +15 °C; –15 °C

Дополнительно: [Таблица вычитания](https://megamarket.ru/catalog/details/tablica-vychitaniya-tablica-slozheniya-plakat-laminirovannyy-dvustoronniy-100028605975/).

Comment: Вот это я понимаю — супер-Римма!

Comment: По-моему, ссылку на «Примеры на вычитание» лучше убрать из Вашего ответа: ведь очень многие из приведённых там примеров записаны совсем не по Мильчину. 

Comment: А *что* там не по Мильчину?

Comment: «**98-19**», «**95-20**» и т. д. (Фото в комментариях привести не смогу.)

Comment: Такая запись ошибочна. Мильчин пишет: знаки отбиваются... А в Вашем примере вообще не минус, а дефис. Вот тетрадки с таблицей умножения. Все примеры с пробелами. (https://mysku.club/blog/russia-stores/85341.html) Что лучше воспринимается: **6х9=54** или **6 х 9 = 54**? А если уравнения с буквами и нецелыми числами (абстрактно): **0,6aх0,9b=0,54**  Сливается ведь все воедино, где что — не поймешь.

Comment: «_А в Вашем примере вообще не минус, а дефис._» === Римма, это не **в моём примере**, а в примере, на который ведёт ссылка **в Вашем ответе**. Потому я написал выше, что эту ссылку лучше было бы убрать из Вашего ответа.

Comment: Ну не вижу я этого примера! Но чтобы никого не смущать, изничтожу ссылку. Спасибо, Слава, за замечание. Сразу и не поняла, в чем дело.

Comment: А если так: _(–)100 000_? Пятизначное и более число всегда содержит пробел. А если к нему ещë и минус добавить, его отбить пробелом от _100 000_? Ваш ответ мне бы очень пригодился.